# Cómo eliminar parámetros después del .php?

Tags: php, javascript, url, condiciones

Cómo puedo eliminar los parámetros que muestra después de .php 
Ejemplo: `www.prueba.com/index.php?1` 
Realicé un inicio de sesión, donde puse que si index.php?0 entonces me mostrara un modal indicando que la contraseña y usuario son incorrectos. Mi problema es que una vez que muestra el modal me sigue dejando la url igual, no sé exactamente que función podría utilizar para quitar el `?0` al cerrar el modal.

Código JS:

```
var loc = document.location.href;
  var getString = loc.split('?')[1];

  if (getString == 0){
swal(
  'Usuario y contraseña incorrectos',
  'Revisa tus datos',
  'error'
)
  }else if(getString == 1){
    swal(
  'Contraseña incorrecta',
  'Revisa tus datos',
  'error'
)
```

Comment: no se puede hacer desde javascript si o si tendrás que hacer un re direccionamiento para limpiar la url

Comment: @FranciscoNúñez Entonces cómo puedo indicar que una vez que se haya mostrado el modal me redireccione para limpiar la url

Comment: te dejo una respuest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

intenta con esto no lo he podido experimentar me dejas tus comentarios saludos:

```
window.history.pushState("object", "title", "URL Correcta");
```

Comment: Ah sí, ya me funcionó lo utilicé así: history.pushState(Obj, " ", " "); 
Gracias :)